# Which is faster for an MCU? Calculating Steinhart-Hart or search in Look-up Table?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, thermistor

Let say we are to measure 0-100 degree Celsius in 0.1 degree resolution by using an NTC. For a particular MCU which is faster (takes less time to reach the result) :
a) Reading NTC value via ADC and calculate the result using Steinhart-Hart algorithm?
or
b) Reading NTC value via ADC and compare it with the entire pre-constructed look-up table to find the result?

Comment: Really depends on the MCU...

Comment: And the only way to know for sure is to implement it both ways and do some timing analysis

Answer (score 7):

Almost surely lookup table will be faster, but you shouldn't really be concerned with speed when you're talking about reading temperature, with a doubtless glacially slow thermistor at that.

Unless you're talking about 1990s 4-bit mask-programmed micro running off a watch crystal, that is.

Comment: Thanks Spehro. May be I should have asked more clearly:) Speed of reading resistance from NTC is not my concern. The resistance change speed of NTC is not, either. In fact, I wanted to know (after reading the resistance from NTC) which method takes less time for the MCU to achieve the result. In the first method MCU has to do heavy calculations like Log and 1/x operations with floating point. Whereas in the second method, MCU will work on integers but has to compare the read value with the 1000 values stored in the lookup table.

Comment: @Nkgunel -- that sounds like a really inefficient way to handle a lookup table.

Comment: Binary search of 1000 values takes 10 steps.

Comment: You set up the table so you can use the ADC output as an index.  No searching required.  Each ADC value represents a different temperature, if you have enough resolution.

Comment: @Nkgunel I understand what you asked. My point is that the bandwidth of a processor is so much higher than the sensor bandwidth that it might be 1000x faster, but if it's still using 1% of the processor bandwidth, there's no point making it 0.001%. If you have a low resolution ADC,  something like 10 bits or 12 bits  you can simply generate a table  using Steinhart-Hart once and the ADC output is an index to the table. That's perfectly adequate for some applications.

Comment: For example, HVAC where you really only care about temperatures near normal room temperature. With a more precise application, or one that has a wide temperature range, the dynamic range of the signal is large and you end up using a table plus interpolation because it uses so much memory to have a table 2 or 3 or 4 bytes by 2^16 , let alone 2^24. Cubic splines are a nice form of interpolation. But you can also use the equations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that "faster" is your concern.  The lookup table will always be faster, even assuming you need to do a linear interpolation between two entries (which you should do with integer math!!).  The lookup table may or may not use more memory, keeping in mind that you might need to load floating point libraries to use the Steinhart-Hart equations. I suppose you might need to know whether your processor has a floating point unit, whether your application is memory-tight, or whether you're already loading the float libraries for some other purpose.

Lastly, as Spehro pointed out, temperature systems are slow systems, and you don't need all that much of a sample rate.  If you have all the time in the world to do your math, avoiding S-H equations isn't particularly important.

You're asking for an optimization, and as usual, the best approach depends on details of your special situation that you haven't shared.

As for searching through your lookup table entries, this feels unnecessary.  Just map your A/D value to the correct index, and interpolate.  For example, let's say your A/D value is going to map between 0 and Vcc/2, that would be 0-(2^11) on a 12 bit ADC.  Let's also say that you can have 2^8-1 elements in your lookup table.  Integer divide your ADC value by 2^3, and use that as the index in your lookup table.  You can then interpolate for the bottom three bits.  No decisions, no sorts.  Your map from ADC to index may be a little more complicated, but it will be a first order equation.

Comment: Thank you Scott. You are right, my question was not clear enough. That's why I tried to explain more in my comment just below Spehro's answer. In my project I have 5 NTCs and I read them once every second. Doing Steinhart-Hart calculation 5 times every second consumes processing power considerably. So that I wanted to know what people may suggest before I go for the look-up table method. By the way, I have enough memory space. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks Scott!! Mapping the A/D value to the index is a great idea and will be the fastest running solution for me. I have never thought that:)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you store(MAP) the whole lookup table in the RAM memory there is no need to compute anyhthing further. This will be the fastest.  The search will also be faster as the data is stored in ether increasing or a decreasing order.

The MCUs depending on their capacities might try to match the speed but on an average, the look up table will be fastest.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand from both your and Spehro's answer that the look-up table method will produce the result faster.

Answer (score 2):

We've done it both ways.  But on recent jobs, we have gone with the look up table (LUT) approach.  For our 12-bit ADC that provided the digitized voltages from the thermistors, we just built a 4096 entry LUT.

One of the reasons for doing it this way is that it made it easier for us to update the LUT without having to go through the formal SCR (Software Change Request) process.  The LUT was a hardware engineering supplied artifact that resided in a Flash memory that was separate from the software executable image, and we had the ability to update that LUT pretty much whenever we needed to, though we did have to follow the CM (Configuration Management) process.

Comment: Politics rules! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lookup table is faster, but not always.

In a hypothetical processor with a data cache miss penalty of several hundred clocks, but a fully pipelined FPU, often computing transcendental functions is faster than taking a cache miss because the lookup table doesn't fit.  If your processor is a GPU, a lookup that doesn't fit in its local memory can be as slow or slower.  If you suspect your processor is one of those, then benchmarking each algorithm over the full statistical range of your data, and comparing results is a better bet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the useful information.

Comment: The tags chosen as well as the text of the question indicate that the processor is a microcontroller. I think it is unlikely that there is a data cache or a pipelined FPU.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson There are microcontrollers such as some Cortex M7 parts that have a double-precision FPU on chip. Even if a lowly PIC is capable of the measurement, you may be pushed into a better processor because you need modern communications such as Ethernet.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Even the Cortex-M4 has an FPU option...but are they pipelined so they can execute transcendental functions faster than dealing with a cache miss? Can we assume that the OP is looking at an M4 or better? I honestly don't know the answer to that, but I thought this answer needed to have a better sense of the context of the question.